# Laravel 5.3 Trait not found

Tags: php, laravel, traits

Hello i am trying to use a trait from controller in my register controller but it can't seem to find it

the error message:

```
Trait 'MailVerification' not found
```

The class in which i want to use the trait

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;
    use MailVerification;
```

Here i call the function

```
 protected function create(array $data)
 {
    $mail = $data['email'];

    $this->sendVerification($mail);
```

Here is the trait in the class i am trying to import it from

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Mail\TestMail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Session;

trait MailVerification
{
    public function sendVerification($mail)
    {
        $verification_code = str_random(30);
        Mail::send('mail.verify', ['verification_code' => $verification_code, 'mail' => $mail], function ($message) use ($mail)
        {
            $message->from('test@laravel.com');
            $message->to($mail);
        });
        Session::flash('message', "Please check you're email to verify your account");

        return redirect('/');
    }   
}

class MailController extends Controller
{
```

I have the trait outside of my class i don't know if this is correct but it was giving me an error while it was inside the class.

Comment: What is MailController doing inside your trait?

Comment: So i shouldn't have the trait in another class?
Should i have it in a seperate file?
I have done that now but don't know if this is correct 
@prateekkathal

Comment: Yes ofcourse! Traits should always be made separate! As suggested in my answer, you should move your traits to `App\Traits` folder and keep your controllers separate!!! Same goes for the rest of the code....

Comment: Okay
I put the trait named MailVerification.php in app/Traits now
I'm still getting error though on the line that i use this
 use RegistersUsers, MailVerification;
It says that it can't find the trait even though the location it says it exactly where the file is

Comment: Can you edit your above question according to all the new changes... and once again, I ask you for a screenshot of your directory structure...

Answer (score 1):

The namespace of your controller **RegisterController** and your trait **MailVerification** is different...

So, you'll have to add this line to your **RegisterController**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\MailVerification;
```

Also, I suggest you to put all your traits inside `App\Traits` folder instead of your controller. Try following a simpler way if possible :)

Edit --

This is how you register controller should look like

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\MailVerification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers, MailVerification;

    //Your code here....
}
```

Comment: If i try that i get this error.
Trait 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\App\Http\Controllers\MailVerification' not found

Comment: And if i use use \App\Http\Controllers\MailVerification;
i get Trait 'App\Http\Controllers\MailVerification' not found

Comment: Can you answer my comment (on your question). Can I have the screenshot of the way your folders and files are structures in the tree view. Also, just for giving it a try, can you put the RegisterController outside the Auth and in the App\Http\Controllers folder?

Comment: Ok i fixed it by setting the use outside of the class in the registercontroller
But now it says that my sendVerification doesn't exist.

Comment: I edited my answer to ensure you weren't doing anything wrong :)